# Does a new version support an old version of Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have ruby version 1.9.3 and rails version 4.1.1.

Now I have a running project and every thing is ok.

I imported an old project (X) and bundled all required gems, but an error message prevents me from running the (X) project.

```
ruby script/server        
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! called from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:34.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in called from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:322.
.
.
.
.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:268:in `==': undefined method `name' for "abstract":String (NoMethodError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `==='        
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `block in matching_specs'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:412:in `block in each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:411:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:411:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:73:in `add_load_paths'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `block in add_gem_load_paths'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from C:/Sites/demo/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from script/server:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: you are using rails 2.3.5 in ruby 1.9.3? If yes then you can't do that and you'll have to install ruby 1.8.7 to run that

Comment: but when I run the command

Comment: checkout the link for rails 2.3 docs in my answer

Comment: Im sorry, but i run the command (rails -v = 1.9.3), I don't know where the version 2.3.5 came?

Comment: you are using ruby 1.9.3 and your projects rails version is 2.3.5 :)

Comment: ok I'll try to install the version 1.8.7 with 1.9.3

Comment: you are still confused about the rails version and ruby version. In your project YOUR RAILS VERSION IS 2.3.5 AND NOT 1.9.3( this is the current ruby version you are using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked your logs and it says

> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
>   => Booting WEBrick
>   => Rails 2.3.5 application starting

**So you are using Ruby 1.9.3 to run a rails 2.3.5 application. If you look at [rails 2.3 docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#ruby-1-9-1-support), you can't run a rails 2.3.5 app in ruby 1.9.3 and you'll have to install ruby 1.8 or 1.9.1 to run your project**

**Fix**

If you are using rvm then you can install ruby 1.8.7 as it's a stable version by :

```
rvm install 1.8.7
```